# SSIS Derived Column Character cleaning error

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, ssis

I have Table A and need to get the result as shown in Table B.

```
Table A

S.no  Name
1     xy rz Jr
2     yz re Sr
3     yr, rq, Sr.


Table B 

S.no Name
1    xy, rz, Jr.
2    yz, re, Sr.
3    yr, rq, Sr.
```

I have tried removing the special characters initially and then incorporate in later stage but I am unable to arrange them in the required output format

Comment: What's the "special characters"?

Comment: like removing , and . from table A and generalizing all the data

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution for you :

1- Try to apply a transformation to your column to clear the special characters (For exemple '.', ',') :

```
REPLACE(
  REPLACE( @[User::val3_]
    ,","
    ,"")
  ,"."
  ,"")
```

2- Then you can apply this code to transform your column :

```
    @[User::val]+"------"+
(LEFT(@[User::val],2)+", ")
+
(LEFT(
  TRIM(
    REPLACE(@[User::val]
                      ,(LEFT(@[User::val],2))
                      ,"") )
  ,2)+", ")
+
(LEFT(
  TRIM(
    REPLACE(TRIM( REPLACE(@[User::val],LEFT(@[User::val],2),"") )
            ,(LEFT(
                TRIM(REPLACE(@[User::val],(LEFT(@[User::val],2)),"") )
                ,2))
            ,"") )
,2)+".")
```

I hope this will help you.

Good Luck

Comment: Hi Jenny, You should implement this code in 2 'Derived column task'apply the first one on a derived column task to transform your special column (to clear it from special characters), then in a second Derived column task apply the second transformation using the code of the second part on the column already cleared from special characters. Good Luck :)

Comment: I am little confused how can derived column have User::val ?

Comment: I used a variable to do tests, but you must replace the @[User::val] with the name of your column in the dataflow :)